# How can I generate a variable conditioning on different columns?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

My dataset:

| country_d | regime_d | country_o | regime_o | year | col_dep_ever | col_dep_end_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 0.0 | United Kingdom | 1.0 | 1948 | 1.0 | 1919.0 |
| Afghanistan | 0.0 | United Kingdom | 1.0 | 1949 | 1.0 | 1919.0 |
| Afghanistan | 0.0 | United Kingdom | 1.0 | 1950 | 1.0 | 1919.0 |
| India | 0.0 | United Kingdom | 1.0 | 1948 | 1.0 | 1920.0 |
| India | 0.0 | United Kingdom | 1.0 | 1949 | 1.0 | 1920.0 |
| Afghanistan | 0.0 | United Kingdom | 1.0 | 1950 | 1.0 | 1920.0 |

I would like to generate a variable that is 1 if "col_dep_ever" is 1 & regim_o and regime_d are different (regime_o=! regime_d).

```
for i in range(len(???)):
    if regime_d[i]== regime_o[i] and col_dep_ever==1:
        df['var1']=2
    elif regime_d[i]!=regime_o[i] and col_dep_ever==1:
        df['var1']=1
    elif regime_d[i]!=regime_o[i] and col_dep_ever==0:
        df['var1']=0
    elif regime_d[i]==regime_o[i] and col_dep_ever==0:
        df['var1']=0
    else:
        df['var1']=None
```

Comment: how is your data_set stored / read? what have you tried? what is the exact issue?

Comment: I am not sure about the  `for i in range(len(???)):`

Comment: well, the length of your data set, since you're using lists and they should be of the same size you can use len(regime_o)

Comment: also your code contradicts what you want to achieve, do you want just a value of 1 or 0 or is the 2 needed or a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give an answer to 1 row, you can generalise it with a loop.
Also based on the 0 lines of code you provided us I had to make some assumption. but this should resolve your issue

```py
## I have no idea why it is not just a boolean but ok
my_binary_data = 1 if col_dep_ever == '1.0' and regime_o=! regime_d else 0
```

A better way is to just use a True/False value :

```py
my_boolean_value = col_dep_ever == '1.0' and regime_o=! regime_d
```